# Update text box, but a letter remain doesn't get deleted react js

Tags: reactjs

I have created an update control input

```
let uVal=this.state.editedVal?this.state.editedVal:this.props.eVal;

<input type="text" value={uVal} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

The control has either state or props value when I start editing the field the first letter when gets deleted the entire props value appear default again or in other case never gets deleted what can be done to make it editable entirely.

Can anyone let me know what's wrong?

Thank you any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're doing a truthy check. The condition check of this ternary:

```
let uVal=this.state.editedVal?this.state.editedVal:this.props.eVal;
```

Will return false if the `editedVal` property doesn't exist, but also if the `editedVal` property is a range of other things, including **an empty string**. So when you delete all the characters in the input, the value is an empty string and changes the result of that ternary.

In general, it's not recommended to rely on truthy/falsy checks in Javascript, as it can cause issues exactly like the one you're facing, as well as many other hard to debug problems and weird behaviour. Check for specific conditions and use `===`.

As a side note, you can shorten your current ternary to this:

```
let uVal = this.state.editedVal || this.props.eVal;
```

And that will give the same result as yours. Though you may end up changing the truthy check technique so that new way may not be relevant.

Comment: '||' will give you the exact same error as your current method. It's not a fix for your issue, I was just saying that it was shorthand for the way you were currently doing it. Read everything above that for the reason you're getting your issue. Your fix will have to revolve around that. I can't give you the actual answer, since it will depend on how your components are structured and implemented.