# search results are dislayed on second click n not for the first react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

M doing asearch what happens is search results are dislayed on second click n not for the first react js  i dont unstand whats happenindg on the second click
this is not dynamic have used statiic value

any help is appreciated

```
handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    listArr: this.props.list.filter(e1 => e1 === this.state.value),
  });
  this.props.searchItem(this.state.listArr);
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input type="Submit" value="sech" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

what is it displaying onto second click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so after you set your state other parts of your function can't catch up. Try with a callback with `setState`.

```
handleSubmit(e){   
     e.preventDefault();
     this.setState({
         listArr:this.props.list.filter(e1=> 
         (e1===this.state.value))
     }, () => this.props.searchItem(this.state.listArr) );  
}
```

**Update after comments**

As I tried to explain, `setState` is asynchronous. It does not update the state immediately. First, you set your state with filtering. But when you invoke `searchItem` function, `setState` is still trying to update the state, it does not finish its job. So, your `listArr` is still empty or not updated at that time. Hence, your search does not work.

But why does it work in the second time? Because when you hit the button for the second time `setState` has already finished its job, there is actually a `listArr` now. So, your search works.

Here, callback function in `setState` waits for the update, then invokes what you provide to it.

Comment: Thanks:)  can u help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923504/update-text-box-but-a-letter-remain-doesnt-get-deleted-react-js/51923616#51923616